# Applications of Combinatorial Discrepancy Theory

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

**TL;DR: What are some fancy applications of combinatorial discrepancy theory?**

---

## Combinatorial Discrepancy

Consider a set of white balls $\Omega$ and a family $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of Omega. The task is to find a two-coloring of $\Omega$, such that in every set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ the difference between the number of "red" and "blue" balls is as low as possible.

Mathematically, this problem can be described as minimizing the discrepancy of a set system: Let $\Omega$ be a finite set and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a family of subsets of $\Omega$.
The **combinatorial discrepancy** of $\mathcal{A}$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{disc}(\mathcal{A})=\min_{\chi: \Omega \mapsto \{-1,1\}} \max_{A \in \mathcal{A}} |\sum_{a \in A}\chi(a)|.
\end{equation}
It has been shown, that for $|\Omega|=|\mathcal{A}|=n$, $\operatorname{disc}(A) \leq 6\sqrt{n}$ (see [Six Standard Deviations Suffice](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1985-289-02/S0002-9947-1985-0784009-0/)). Finding colorings $\chi$ that minimize the discrepancy is also a topic of current research (see [Constructive Algorithms for Discrepancy Minimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2259)).

I have read that combinatorial discrepancy was used in computer science , but not how and where exactly it is used.

**Where is combinatorial discrepancy used in CS? What other fields is combinatorial discrepancy used in (apart from coloring balls)?**

Comment: The bin packing problem seems to be one application of discrepany theory. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.2170.pdf

Comment: This is very late, I know, but [this blog post](http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/) has an interesting discussion of application to computer graphics (at the end) and promises more to come in the future.